# Assigning int* from incompatible void *

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
int * generate_code(int *bits, int Fs, int size, int *signal_size, float frameRate)
{
  int sign_prev, i;
  int bit, t, j=0;
  int *x;
  float F0, N, t0, prev_i, F1;
  int temp = 0, temp1, temp2;

  F0 = frameRate * BITS_PER_FRAME;      // Frequency of a train of '0's = 2.4kHz
  F1 = 2*F0;       // Frequency of a train of '1's = 4.8kHz
  N = 2*(float)Fs/F1;   // number of samples in one bit

  sign_prev = -1;
  prev_i = 0;
  x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
  {

    t0 = (i + 1)*N;
    bit = bits[i];
    if( bit == 1 )
    {
      temp1 = (int)round(t0-N/2)-(int)round(prev_i+1)+1;
      temp2 = (int)round(t0)-(int)round(t0-N/2+1)+1;
      temp =j + temp1 + temp2;
      //printf("%d\n", (int)temp);
      x = realloc(x, sizeof(int)*temp);  // 1

      for(t=(int)round(prev_i+1); t<=(int)round(t0-N/2); t++)
      {
        *(x + j) = -sign_prev;
        j++;
      }
      prev_i = t0-N/2;
      for(t=(int)round(prev_i+1); t <= (int)round(t0); t++)
      {
        *(x + j) = sign_prev;
        j++;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // '0' has single transition and changes sign
      temp =j + (int)round(t0)-(int)round(prev_i);
      //printf("%d\n",(int)temp);
      x = realloc(x, sizeof(int)*(int)temp);  // 2
      for(t=(int)round(prev_i); t < (int)round(t0); t++)
      {
        *(x + j) = -sign_prev;
        j++;
      }
      sign_prev = -sign_prev;
    }
    prev_i = t0;
  }

  *signal_size = j;
  return x;
}
```

Both `realloc` lines, marked with `//1` and `//2` on the previous code, give me this error message:

> assigning to int * from incompatible type void *

Because I don't want this code behaving weirdly or crashing on me, obviously, I ask will: I have some problem in the future if I simply cast it to `int *` by doing

```
x = (int*)realloc(x, sizeof(int)*(int)temp);
```

Thanks

Comment: @JackWilliams he doesn't do that. The reallocs in his code aren't cased. He says he doesn't want to do that.

Comment: You are most likely compiling your source code using a C++ compiler. A `void*` is compatible with `int*` (or any other data pointer for that matter) in C. So you wouldn't need the cast in C.

Comment: @l3x: It's not *compatible* (that word has a very specific meaning in C), but it can be implicitly converted by an assignment. You might call it "assignment-compatible", though the C standard doesn't use that term.

Comment: Note that `ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);` is dangerous because if the reallocation fails, you've (usually) lost your pointer to the original memory — you just overwrote `ptr` with a null pointer.  Always use a variant on `void *new_space = realloc(ptr, new_size); if (new_space != 0) ptr = new_space;`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, a value of type `void*` (such as the value returned by `realloc`) may be assigned to a variable of type `int*`, or any other object pointer type. The value is implicitly converted.

The most likely explanation for the error message is that you're compiling the code as C++ rather than as C.  Make sure the source file name ends in `.c`, not `.C` or `.cpp`, and make sure your compiler is configured to compile as C rather than as C++.

(Casting the result of `realloc` or `malloc` is considered poor style in C.  In C++, the cast is necessary, but you normally wouldn't use `realloc` or `malloc` in C++ in the first place.)

Comment: Important point about not using capital .C for C code - GCC at least interprets that as C++.  Given the .c extension, few if any compilers then need explicit options for C compilation, but certainly you must be sure there is no explicit option forcing C++ compilation, overriding the extension.

Comment: You nailed it! By mistake that code is in a `.cpp` file!

Answer (score 1):

This should work in C. Are you perhaps using a C++ compiler to compile this? For example, some big company based in Redmond refuses to properly support a contemporary C implementation. Their compiler is C++ by default and needs some option to whack it into a C compiler.

You have `stdlib.h` included? Then you don't need the casts. In fact, it is best practice to *not* cast the malloc return.

Comment: No option is required to force C compilation in VC++, it is sufficient to just use the .c file-name extension.  C99 support does not appear to be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

All `alloc`-style functions in C return memory addresses with the most strict alignment, so the cast can't give a pointer that isn't a valid `int` pointer.